# i want to use the ical but have few items based upon different timezones

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

i had the calendar file build in very old way, i am trying to use the ical with this

```
https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/5c62d02f87c644c78b25
```

because i have few events which are in different `timezones` and they should appear properly in the timezone, not sure how will i be able to fix the above `url` with my code, any guidance will help

i tried to use it but the values seems t be hardcoded

```
function iCalUS2(stEvent) {
    var vCal = ArrayNew(1);
    var date_now = Now();
    if (not isStruct(stEvent)){
        throw(message="invalid iCal Struct", detail="stEvent must be a struct");
    }
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "method")) stEvent.method = "REQUEST";  // PUBLISH adds directly to a custom calendar
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "organizerName")) stEvent.organizerName = CGI.Server_Name;
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "organizerEmail")) stEvent.organizerEmail = "info@#CGI.Server_Name#";
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "subject")) stEvent.subject = "Event subject";
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "location")) stEvent.location = "Event location";
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "description")) stEvent.description = "Event description goes here
Provide the complete event details";
    /* This value must be in Pacific time!!! */
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "startTime"))  stEvent.startTime = ParseDateTime("1/1/1999 14:30");
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "endTime"))  stEvent.endTime = ParseDateTime("1/1/1999 15:30");
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "priority")) stEvent.priority = 1;
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "calendarName")) stEvent.calendarName = "#CGI.Server_Name# Calendar";
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "calendarDescription")) stEvent.calendarDescription = "Event Calendar for #CGI.Server_Name#";
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "timeZone")) stEvent.timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles";
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "status")) stEvent.status = "";
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "sequence")) stEvent.sequence = 0; // Track qty of updates to an event (optional)
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "uid")) stEvent.uid = "#date_now.getTime()#.#CGI.Server_Name#";
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(stEvent, "lastmodified")) stEvent.lastmodified = "";
    arrayAppend(vCal, "BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "VERSION:2.0");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "PRODID: -//SunStar Media//iCalUS//EN");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "METHOD:#Ucase(stEvent.method)#");
    if (stEvent.method IS "request"){
        arrayAppend(vCal, "X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE");
    }   
    arrayAppend(vCal, "X-WR-CALNAME:#ical_escape_text(stEvent.calendarName)#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "X-WR-TIMEZONE:US/Pacific");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "X-WR-RELCALID:#stEvent.uid#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "X-WR-CALDESC:#ical_escape_text(stEvent.calendarDescription)#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "TZID:US/Pacific");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "BEGIN:STANDARD");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "DTSTART:20061101T020000");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "TZOFFSETFROM:-0800");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "TZOFFSETTO:-0700");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "TZNAME:Pacific Time");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "END:STANDARD");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "BEGIN:DAYLIGHT");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "DTSTART:20060301T020000");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "TZOFFSETFROM:-0800");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "TZOFFSETTO:-0700");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "TZNAME:Daylight Savings Time");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "END:DAYLIGHT");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "END:VTIMEZONE");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "BEGIN:VEVENT");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "UID:#stEvent.uid#");  // creates a unique identifier
    if (isDate(stEvent.lastmodified)){
        arrayAppend(vCal, "LAST-MODIFIED:#DateFormat(stEvent.lastmodified,'yyyymmdd')#T#TimeFormat(stEvent.lastmodified,'HHmmss')#");
    }
    arrayAppend(vCal, "ORGANIZER;CN=#ical_escape_text(stEvent.organizerName)#:MAILTO:#stEvent.organizerEmail#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "DTSTAMP:#DateFormat(date_now,'yyyymmdd')#T#TimeFormat(date_now,'HHmmss')#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "DTSTART;TZID=US/Pacific:#DateFormat(stEvent.startTime,'yyyymmdd')#T#TimeFormat(stEvent.startTime,'HHmmss')#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "DTEND;TZID=US/Pacific:#DateFormat(stEvent.endTime,'yyyymmdd')#T#TimeFormat(stEvent.endTime,'HHmmss')#");
    if (LEN(stEvent.status)){
        arrayAppend(vCal, "STATUS:#ucase(stEvent.status)#");
    }
    arrayAppend(vCal, "SEQUENCE:#VAL(stEvent.sequence)#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "SUMMARY:#ical_escape_text(stEvent.subject)#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "LOCATION:#ical_escape_text(stEvent.location)#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "DESCRIPTION:#ical_escape_text(stEvent.description)#");
    if (Find("<", stEvent.description)) {
        arrayAppend(vCal, "X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:#Request.ical_escape_text(stEvent.description, 'html')#");
    }
    if (stEvent.status NEQ "CANCELLED"){
        arrayAppend(vCal, "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY");
        arrayAppend(vCal, "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:2");
    }
    arrayAppend(vCal, "PRIORITY:#stEvent.priority#");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "TRANSP:OPAQUE");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "CLASS:PUBLIC");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "BEGIN:VALARM");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "TRIGGER:-PT30M");  // alert user 30 minutes before meeting begins
    arrayAppend(vCal, "ACTION:DISPLAY");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "END:VALARM");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "END:VEVENT");
    arrayAppend(vCal, "END:VCALENDAR");
    return Trim(arrayToList(vCal, "#chr(13)##chr(10)#"));
}
```

I am doing it like this in my code for Timing,

```
"DTSTAMP:" DateFormat(now(),"yyyymmdd") & "T" & TimeFormat(now(), "HHmmss");
"DTSTART:" DateFormat(startime,"yyyymmdd") & "T" &                  TimeFormat(starttime, "HHmmss");
```

so my biggest concern is to use the timezone with the vtimezone instead of using it globally on the top, because events can have seperate timezones

This is my current code as of now

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
VERSION:2.0 PRODID: -//iCalUS()//EN 
X-WR-CALNAME:My Calendar 
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/new York 
X-WR-CALDESC: 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
UID:5739453945 
DTSTAMP:20181203T214510 
DTSTART:20181126T070000 
DTEND:20181126T100000 
SUMMARY: anything i specify 
LOCATION:Online 
DESCRIPTION:what is written here 
END:VEVENT 
END:VCALENDAR
```

i want to move the timezone to VTimezone but it lots of other values which i do not know how can i add those and i want to remove the value from the TOP

X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/new York because i have multiple events happening in different timezones

please guide

Comment: Have you tried converting your date/times to UTC, then adjusting your TZOFFSET values?

Comment: not exactly....

Comment: You're correct that the values are hardcoded because it looks to me as if the TZOFFSETFROM, TZOFFSETTO, TZID, and TZNAME are set to PST.  I suggest changing those to you're locale appropriate values OR you should be able to provide the TZ offset in your datetime stamps (https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dateTime.html)

Comment: how can i update it in the existing ical function, should i just in the values to it and it will rewrite the evnts or any how?

Comment: Based on the code it looks like stEvent has a property labeled "timeZone".  But the code generating the iCal file does not appear to be using this.  Example:  arrayAppend(vCal, "X-WR-TIMEZONE:#stEvent.timeZone#");  Keep in mind that simply adjusting the X-WR-TIMEZONE may not be enough.  You may also need to use this value to adjust your offsets and tzid.